# Spring getting The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String ";"

Tags: spring, security, spring-security

I am integrating spring SAML with a IDP.While redirecting from application(SP) to IDP login screen, the IDP is appending jsessionid and getting the below exception in browser. First Time I am getting the below exception while redirecting from application page to IDP login page, but second time if I enter the application url it will redirect to idp login page successfully.

Not getting what is the problem,  for other IDP below exception I am not getting, but for a particular IDP which is custom written I am getting the exception for the first time. Anything need to change from SP or IDP side.

Below is the exception got while redirecting to IDP login page from SP.(`Note: example.com is IDP domain`)
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behavior of Spring Security is to deny requests with a semicolon in the URL because it is a common way to perform [Reflected File Download Attacks](https://wiki.owasp.org/index.php/Reflected_File_Download).
The `JSESSIONID` shouldn't be in the path as it can lead to leaking, instead, you could use cookies for that.

The [Spring Security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.0/api/org/springframework/security/web/firewall/StrictHttpFirewall.html#setAllowSemicolon(boolean)) for StrictHttpFirewall explains this behavior.

> Determines if semicolon is allowed in the URL (i.e. matrix variables). The default is to disable this behavior because it is a common way of attempting to perform Reflected File Download Attacks. It is also the source of many exploits which bypass URL based security.
>
> If you are wanting to allow semicolons, please reconsider as it is a very common source of security bypasses. A few common reasons users want semicolons and alternatives are listed below:
>
> Including the JSESSIONID in the path - You should not include session id (or any sensitive information) in a URL as it can lead to leaking. Instead use Cookies.
> Matrix Variables - Users wanting to leverage Matrix Variables should consider using HTTP parameters instead.

Note that you can still disable this behavior by using your custom defined instance of `StrictHttpFirewall` but please reconsider as it is a very common source of security bypasses.

```java
@Bean
public HttpFirewall allowSemicolonHttpFirewall() {
    StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
    firewall.setAllowSemicolon(true);
    return firewall;
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
  super.configure(web);
  web.httpFirewall(allowSemicolonHttpFirewall());
}
```